# Meaning of << and |= in Java

Tags: java, string, operators, unique

There is a question of implementing a code in Java where I have to find if the string has unique characters or not without having to create a new data structure.

The Java implementation was as follows:

```
public static boolean isUniqueChars(String str) { 
    int checker = 0; 
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) { 
        int val = str.charAt(i) - 'a'; 
        if ((checker & (1 << val)) > 0) return false; 
        checker |= (1 << val); 
    } 
    return true; 
}
```

In line 5-6, there's the << that I don't really get.
And in line 6, I don't get what the '|' symbol does.

Could someone give a brief explanation of how this code works?
Thanks.

Comment: Bit wise and bit-shift operators: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html

Comment: Did you consider consulting the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/index.html)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1. For this symbol :** `<<`

In your code : `1 << val` means `(int)Math.pow(2,val) = 2 ^ val`

---

---

**2. For this symbol :** `>>`

```
  >> is  bit-shift operator
```

`x >> N` means (if you view it as a string of binary digits):

The rightmost `N` bits are discarded

The leftmost bit is replicated as many times as necessary to pad the result to the original size (32 or 64 bits),
 **e.g.**

```
00000000000000000000000000101011 >> 2 -> 00000000000000000000000000001010

11111111111111111111111111010100 >> 2 -> 11111111111111111111111111110101
```

---

---

**3. For this symbol :**  `|=`

it  means       bitwise inclusive OR and assignment operator

**E.g:**

```
            checker |= (1<<val) 
is same as  checker |= (2^val)  
is same as  checker = checker | (2^val)    (*)
```

then :      `A  | B    (  | means Binary OR Operator copies a bit if it exists in either operand)`

**Example**

```
   A      = 00101010
   B      = 01101000
 A | B    = 01101010
```

with

```
    0 OR 0 = 0  , 1 OR 0 = 1
    1 OR 1 = 1  , 0 OR 1 = 1
```

Comment: He's not asking about `>>`, he asks about `<<`. the stuff about sign extension is irrelevant and confusing.

Answer (score 2):

Using Ziprox's helpful hint that (1 << val) is equivalent to 2^val or Math.pow(2,val).  It becomes much easier to decipher what is happening.

I believe 'int' is 4 bytes long which is 32 bits.  This method is converting each letter in the alphabet (undercase) to number 2 ^ val.  Basically, each letter is represented by a unique bit of the variable checker.  26 letters, 32 bits gives you 6 extra bits that do nothing.

```
checker & (1<<val)
```

will only be true of it has seen the number previously.

```
checker |= (1<<val)
```

is equivalent to

```
checker = (checker | (1<<val))
```

which simply flips that letter's bit from 0 to 1 to indicate that it has been seen.